# Is linear algebra about simultaneous changes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I've been taken linear algebra for about two months, and I spent a lot of time thinking about how this subject can be seen on an intuitive level. The closer I could get is some geometric interpretations, but maybe there's something deeper about it. Recently I realized that all of the applications for vectors (using real numbers) that I could find are nothing more than a bunch of quantities that can be changed simultaneously, even the operations applied on vectors have always something to do with simultaneous operations. Geometric vectors for example are always about simultaneous changes in distances measured on perpendicular planes. Is this always true?

Comment: In my mind linear algebra is about understanding linear transformations, which are the simplest nontrivial functions and therefore a very important and fundamental type of function. In the real-world, there are many input-output relationships which have the property that doubling the input has the effect of doubling the output. Linear transformations model this simple type of input-output output relationship. It is not vectors but linear transformations which are the star of the show.

Comment: Stop thinking of vectors as little arrows.  There are so many things that are vectors.  A function is a vector, set of data might be a vector, etc.  Linear Algebra is all over statistics.  What is covariance?  It is an inner product.  It as applications to differential equations.  And as every continuous function is locally linear, there are a slew of problems that we can apply a linear model to.

Comment: I second the first comment, it is the study of so called "nice" structure preserving maps. Its one of the first courses that gives you this notion of two spaces being "the same" which is fancy for saying there exists a linear transformation between them. Furthermore, you study Eigen vectors and values which play a huge role in these transformations. If $L$ is a transformation mapping $V$ into $W$ then an Eigen value is a nonzero scalar such that $L(x) = \lambda x$ for each $x \in V$. (Basically they act as scalars which blow up or shrink things)